# Password protect individual media files based on page password in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, password-protection

I would like to be able to password protect files that are uploaded and displayed per specific page based on the same password created for that page.

Any ideas or plugins?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

So your looking at 2 steps? One to unlock the page, then the same pass unlocks the downloads? Why not just have a hidden content block on page that requires a password to be displayed?

Comment: It would be great if they still only had to enter it once! Basically, I want them to enter it once to see the page, and still have the files that are on that page protected so others can't navigate to them to download..